# Getting back "ResolveIOD" while trying to open HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\ on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, registry

I'm trying to get at the UserData registry subkeys on a C# 3.5 application so I can look up the installed location of an external program to start it.

Doing something like this:

```
RegistryKey installerKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer");
```

and then

```
RegistryKey userDataKey = installerKey.OpenSubKey("UserData");
```

returns null; if I go back and call `installerKey.GetSubKeyNames()` to figure out which subkey names are present under `Installer` it only returns one subkey name: `ResolveIOD`. I haven't been able to find what only being able to find this key indicates.

`regedit` does not show the `ResolveIOD` key being there, and it shows that much more than just that one key is present - `UserData`, `Folders`, `Secure`, etc are all there and not returned by `GetSubKeyNames()` either.

This is my first time accessing anything in the Installer section of the registry hive, so I've probably done something wrong. Is there some kind of special permission I have to request in order to read these (probably sensitive, security-wise) keys from a client application, or is this generally not an acceptable thing to do on Windows 7 and I should find an alternative way of figuring out where the program is located?

Because I'm seeing this mentioned on other registry questions: This is running as a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: You probably need to run this in compatibility mode. HKLM is admin specific in Win7. Try HKCU perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

First, to ensure you are accessing the 64-bit registry rather than the Wow6432Node sandbox, use the RegOpenKeyEx function with KEY_WOW64_64KEY (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) included as one of the access options.

pinvoke.net has a C# example: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegOpenKeyEx.html

Also note that with UAC enabled, an unelevated app will, at best, only have read access to HKLM.